# Plotting $ (y/b) $ vs. $ (a/b) $ for a function $ y = f(a, b) $

Tags: plotting

If I have the function `y = a + a b + b`, how do I make a plot of `y/b` vs. `a/b` for `a/b` ratios spanning from 0 to 10?

Comment: If I was you I would rewrite your function with i.e. `yy = y/b` and `aa= a/b` which would give the following equation `yy[aa,b]:=aa+aa*b+1`. You still need to define what b is in the equation.  A typical plot of this would be for b = 1 `Plot[yy[aa,1],{aa,0,10}]`.

Comment: maybe `ParametricPlot[Table[{z, 1 + z + a}, {a, 0, 5, 1/2}], {z, 0, 10}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"a/b", "y/b"}]`?

Comment: ... or `ParametricPlot[{z, 1 + z + a}, {z, 0, 10}, {a, 0, 10}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"a/b", "y/b"}]`?

Comment: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[1 + a + r, {a, 5, 0, -1}], {r, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"a/b", "y/b"}), PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[5, 0, -1], LegendLabel -> "a ="]]`

Answer (score 1):

By introducing a new variable $u=a/b$, your equation $y = a + a b + b$ can be transformed into $y/b = 1 + u + b u)$, which is a function of $b$ and the ratio $a/b$, so the function you want to plot is

```
yOverB[u_, b_] := 1 + u + b u
```

treating $b$ as a parameter. The plot range will over [0, 10] and you will want to label it to clearly show it is a plot of $y/b$ against $a/b$. Like so:

```
Plot[Evaluate[yOverB[u, #] & /@ Range[5]], {u, 0, 10},
  AxesLabel -> {"a/b", "y/b"},
  PlotLegends -> (Row[{"b = ", #}] & /@ Range[5])]
```

[image: plot]